# Can I terminate VBA macro execution with a C# dll

Tags: c#, excel, vba

In VBA I can terminate execution of macros using an `End` statement as follows.

```vb
Sub DoSomeThing()
    Dim test As Boolean
    test = false
    test = function()
    If test Then
        End 'Macro execution is terminated
    End if
End Sub
```

I would like my C# DLL to contain a method that has the same effect?  I am thinking of something along the following line.

```cs
public void DoSomething_CSharp()
{
    var test = false;
    test = Function();
    if (test)
    {
        //Call a command here that terminates execution of the VBA macro that calls this method.
    }
}
```

I realize the `End` is a VBA statement, but I don't know how to reach VBA statements from within a C# DLL. (As this question demonstrates, I am new to C#.)

Comment: Why don't you return a boolean to your VBA and then close from there?

Comment: Use ***System.Environment.Exit(0);***

Comment: No.  You'll have to do it with `throw new Exception("Macro aborted");`.  Formulating a better message to tell your user why you decided to ignore their command is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `End` in VBA do?

- In the MS Access Runtime, it interrupts execution and closes the application.
- In other Office applications (such as Excel, or Access in "non-runtime" mode) it interrupts execution and falls back through the call stack to the UI layer.

Since you tagged your question with "Excel", I assume that you want the second behavior.

In .NET, the only way to "jump through the call stack" is to throw an exception:

```
throw new Exception("...some message...");
```

This, however, will cause your VBA application to execute its error handler. If you want to return a specific error code (so that you can handle and/or ignore expected exceptions at the UI layer), you can throw an exception with a specific `HResult`, see the following answer for details:

- [Error Handling in C# / VBA COM Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4621504/87698)